# How to choose machine type for 1000 active users on Compute Engine

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

help me choose cpu and memory please

I'm going to run my wordpress site on Google Compute Engine.

I have about 1000 active users online at the same time and about 50,000 - 80,000 visitors per day.

I'm going to choose ssd/10gb

But I'm not sure how to choose vcpu and memmory

Help me choose please.

Comment: With the data that you have provided, you will get poor answers. If you already have a website, measure it. The most important factor is responsiveness (page load time). If you don't have a website, pick any instance size and then monitor it. You will quickly figure out performance requirements. I could think of maybe 50 questions to ask before I recommened a particular design. Tip: the correct question is `what database design should I select for my Wordpress site?`.

Answer (score 0):

Hosting consists of many services that work together to provide the web pages to the end user, and all hosting has it’s bottlenecks.

To have a resilient and scalable website, i will recommend you incorporate auto-scaling into your design. The following links will assist in this regard:

1. [Globally Auto-scaling a Service on Compute Engine](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/globally-autoscaling-a-web-service-on-compute-engine&sa=D&ust=1543442834822000&usg=AFQjCNHeMLGqLQCMrYHB7-xvgwuvDa9LEg)
2. [Designing robust systems](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/robustsystems&sa=D&ust=1543442834822000&usg=AFQjCNEqSJHCsyY2yVDbjzsQ2d_CiDuSag)
3. [Building scalable and resilient application on google cloud platform](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://cloud.google.com/solutions/scalable-and-resilient-apps&sa=D&ust=1543442834822000&usg=AFQjCNGabO5GzYu6J1DYtLULBuhAvz1fng)